# Auto send GCM push notifications from server

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

Pretty much what the title says.

I got a perfect working GCM system which sends GCM push notifications to multiple devices **on button click**, though im building now a calendar system where users have to register his GCM register id.
Than 24hours before the task runs out i send them a message , 12 hours before the task runs out aswell & on the same time as the task runs out a new message.

It works when i for example refresh the page which sends the GCM push notifications, on the times which i said above.

But i want to let the server send these push notifications automatic.

Any ways how to trigger a function automatic without being on the webpage which sends the GCM or not on the application? 
All help is welcome.

Also if there is a way to use this system in the application itself, tell me pls! 
I think i can only make it work to use cron in the server itself, but I don't got acces to it. 
Thats why im open for all suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cron Job In Hosting, so its take a time and write a php script that send the push notification, then cron job on specific time run that script and notification will be send.